# Default assignee for issues

Tags: gitlab

Is there a way to set a default assignee for newly cerated issues? All new issues are set to `Unassigned`. This way no notifications about this issue are sent out unless people set their notification levels to `watching`. And notification settings can only be set for entire groups or projects you are explicitly set as member.

Comment: +1 The issue could be assigned to the master of the repository or a configuration for each project to set the default assignee.

Comment: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/19570

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I have finally found a solution for this myself. It's possible to implement default assignees using [templates](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/user/project/description_templates.html) and [quick actions](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/user/project/quick_actions.html):

Simply put `/assign @username` into the templates. This way you can even define *multiple* default assignees for different kinds of issues.

Comment: The problem with this seems to be, that the reporter has to manually choose your newly created template to make this work, right? Unfortunately there seems to be nothing like default.md.

Comment: ``guest`` can create issues too, but the ``/assign @username`` not work for ``guest``.

Comment: Is there a way to conditionally assign `@JohnDoe` only if the creator of the merge request is not JohnDoe, if its john itself the assignee should be `@JaneDoe` ?

Comment: @SvenGeggus try to use `Default.md` capital "D"

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the answer of mattmilten and the comment of Sven Geggus, which allow to automatically assign an issue:

With Gitlab 14.8 there is [now the option to create default issue templates](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/description_templates.html#set-a-default-template-for-merge-requests-and-issues)